# Grouping data by specific years in python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I want to create a dataframe that is grouped by region and date which shows the average age of a region during specific years. so my coloumns would look something like

> region,   year,   average age

so far I have:

```
#specify aggregation functions to column'age'    
ageAverage = {'age':{'average age':'mean'}} 

#groupby and apply functions    
ageDataFrame = data.groupby(['Region', data.Date.dt.year]).agg(ageAverage)
```

This works great, but how can I make it so that I only group data from specific years? say for example between 2010 and 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need filter first by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
ageDataFrame = (data[data.Date.dt.year.between(2010, 2015)]
                  .groupby(['Region', data.Date.dt.year])
                  .agg(ageAverage))
```

Also in [last version of pandas 0.22.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming) get:

> SpecificationError: cannot perform renaming for age with a nested dictionary

Correct solution is specify column in list after `groupby` and aggregate by `tuple` - first value is new column name and second aggregate function:

```
np.random.seed(123)

rng = pd.date_range('2009-04-03', periods=10, freq='13M')
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng,
                     'Region':['reg1'] * 3 + ['reg2'] * 7,
                     'average age': np.random.randint(20, size=10)})  
print (data)
        Date Region  average age
0 2009-04-30   reg1           13
1 2010-05-31   reg1            2
2 2011-06-30   reg1            2
3 2012-07-31   reg2            6
4 2013-08-31   reg2           17
5 2014-09-30   reg2           19
6 2015-10-31   reg2           10
7 2016-11-30   reg2            1
8 2017-12-31   reg2            0
9 2019-01-31   reg2           17

ageAverage = {('age','mean')}

#groupby and apply functions    
ageDataFrame = (data[data.Date.dt.year.between(2010, 2015)]
                 .groupby(['Region', data.Date.dt.year])['average age']
                 .agg(ageAverage))
print (ageDataFrame)
             age
Region Date     
reg1   2010    2
       2011    2
reg2   2012    6
       2013   17
       2014   19
       2015   10
```

Comment: Oh great! I had no idea I could use between. Thanks a lot, worked perfectly.

Comment: Kind of related but random question, I'm trying to figure out how to plot that dataframe in a boxplot, can't seem to get it right. What I have so far using seaborn: `sns.plot(kind='box', y='age', x='date', hue='age',
               data=ageDataFrame, size=8, aspect=1.5, legend_out=true)`

Any ideas?

Comment: @user3452963 - I think need first `reset_index()` like `ageDataFrame = (data[data.Date.dt.year.between(2010, 2015)]
                 .groupby(['Region', data.Date.dt.year])['average age']
                 .agg(ageAverage)
                 .reset_index())
print (ageDataFrame)` and then  `sns.boxplot(y='age', x='Date', hue='age', data=ageDataFrame)`, [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

Comment: @user3452963 - Not sure, but it seems problem is need data which are not aggregated.

Comment: @user3452963 - e.g. I test `np.random.seed(123)

L = list('abcde')
N = 100
rng = pd.date_range('2009-04-03', periods=N, freq='1M')
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng,
                     'Region':np.random.choice(L, size=N),
                     'average age': np.random.rand(N)})  
print (data)

data = data[data.Date.dt.year.between(2010, 2015)]
data.Date = data.Date.dt.year
sns.boxplot(y='average age', x='Date', hue='Region', data=data)`

Answer (score 1):

Two variations using @jezrael's data (thx)
These are very close to what @jezrael has already shown.  Only view this as a demonstration of what else can be done.  As pointed out in the comments by @jezrael, it is better to pre-filter first as it reduces overall processing.

### `pandas.IndexSlice`

instead of prefiltering with `between`

```
data.groupby(
    ['Region', data.Date.dt.year]

)['average age'].agg(
    [('age', 'mean')]

).loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 2010:2015], :]

             age
Region Date     
reg1   2010    2
       2011    2
reg2   2012    6
       2013   17
       2014   19
       2015   10
```

---

### `between` as part of the `groupby`

```
data.groupby(
    [data.Date.dt.year.between(2010, 2015),
     'Region', data.Date.dt.year]

)['average age'].agg(
    [('age', 'mean')]

).loc[True]

             age
Region Date     
reg1   2010    2
       2011    2
reg2   2012    6
       2013   17
       2014   19
       2015   10
```

Comment: I think for better performance is best first remove unnecessary data and then `groupby` - generally less data processing, better performance. What do you think?

Comment: I totally agree.  I'll was just about to edit further.  Was checking other questions first (-: